# Expansion files not downloading from Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, apk-expansion-files

I'm creating a cordova plugin that downloads expansion files from the play store. 
I implemented it like [this](http://sapandiwakar.in/how-to-set-up-android-app-to-support-expansion-files/).

But when I start my app, nothing happens. `REQUEST TO START DOWNLOAD` was called yet. But nothing further. `onStart()` should be called for example (my class implements the IDownloaderClient).

```
Log.d(TAG, "REQUEST TO START DOWNLOAD");
int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(context, pendingIntent, DownloaderService.class);
```

My apkfile description looks like this:

```
private static final XAPKFile[] xAPKS = {
        new XAPKFile(
                true, // true signifies a main file
                1000012, // the version of the APK that the file was uploaded against
                443975466L // the length of the file in bytes
        )
};
```

The version number ist the one of my apk file. My expansion file has the 1000006.

The byte length was shown me by my phone's file manager. Actually, it's  423 MB, but in byte it's 443975466. This said the manager.

In my downloaderService implementation I added the Base 64 key:

```
public static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "MY_KEY";
private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[]{4, 7, -32, -3, 43, 4, -9, -44, 51, 22, -28, -1, 2, 22, -6, -11, -1, 4, -2, 38}; // TODO Replace with random numbers of your choice
```

(What does SALT actually is? Why random numbers?)

So, are these entries correct?

If yes: Why does nothing happen?

**EDIT**

I downloaded the expansion file in alpha version and test my app building it directly on my device.

**EDIT 2**

`mDownloaderClientStub.connect(context);` should be called in `onResume()`. But my `onResume(multitasking)` method is not called. Adding this code directly behind

```
mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub(this, DownloaderService.class);
```

didn't work either.